# Dynamic dropdown list, pagination and search bar with Ajax/PHP/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to generate dynamic page with ajax containing pagination, `dropdown` list, and search bar.

Search bar, pagination and `dropdown` list are managed well and adapt themselves as needs one.

Now, concerning search bar, when I try to search something, and when there is more than 5 results, if I click on page 2 for example, the next results are not displayed !

No error is indicated in logs!

Would it be possible to be pointed in the right direction please?

```
<?php
require('config/config.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['flash']))
{
    foreach($_SESSION['flash'] as $type => $message)
    {
        echo $message;
    }
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}

$nb_per_page = !empty($_POST['nb_per_page']) ? $_POST['nb_per_page'] : 5;
$search = !empty($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : "";
$p = !empty($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : 1;
$output = "";

$result = getList($nb_per_page, $search, $p, $cnx);

showList($result['list']);
pagination($result['nb_pages'], $p);

function getList($nb_per_page, $search, $p, $cnx)
{
    $nb_per_page = intval($nb_per_page);
    $start = intval(($p-1) * $nb_per_page);
    $where = "";
    if($search != "")
    {
        $where .= "WHERE lastName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR firstName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR age LIKE '%".$search."%' OR scheduleRange LIKE '%".$search."%' OR phoneNumber LIKE '%".$search."%' OR email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR candidacyType LIKE '%".$search."%'";
    }

    $query = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidacies ".$where." LIMIT :start, :nb_per_page");
    $query->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':nb_per_page', $nb_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

    $list = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $query = $cnx->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalResults FROM candidacies '.$where.' ');
    if($search != "")
    {
        $where .= "WHERE lastName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR firstName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR age LIKE '%".$search."%' OR scheduleRange LIKE '%".$search."%' OR phoneNumber LIKE '%".$search."%' OR email LIKE '%".$search."%' OR candidacyType LIKE '%".$search."%'";
    }
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $nb = $result->totalResults;

    $nb_pages = ceil($nb / $nb_per_page);
    if($nb_pages < 1)
    {
        $nb_pages = 1;
    }

    return array(
        "list" => $list,
        "nb" => $nb,
        "nb_pages" => $nb_pages
        );
}

function showList($list)
{
    $output = "";
    $output .= '
        <table class="table table-striped" id="candidaciesTable">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">lastName</th>
                    <th scope="col">firstName</th>
                    <th scope="col">Âge</th>
                    <th scope="col">Schedule Range</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Candidacy Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    ';

    foreach($list as $key => $value)
    {
        $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["lastName"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["firstName"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["age"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["scheduleRange"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["phoneNumber"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["email"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["candidacyType"])."</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btn btn-light btnViewCandidacy' id=".$value['id'].">
                            <i class='far fa-eye'></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class='btn btn-info' id='btnEditCandidacy' onclick='editCandidacy(".$value['id'].")'>
                            <i class='far fa-edit'></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger' id='btnDeleteCandidacy' onclick='deleteCandidacy(".$value['id'].")'>
                            <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }

    $output .= "
        </tbody>
    </table>";

    echo $output;
}

function pagination($nb_pages, $page)
{
    $output = "";
    $output .= "<div class='pagination-centered'>";
    /*if($page > 1)
    {
        $output .= '<a class="paginationLink" id="'.$i.'">Prev</a>';
    }*/
    for($i = 1; $i <= $nb_pages; $i++)
    {
        $class = "";
        if($page == $i){
            $class = "active";
        }
        $output .=  '<a class="paginationLink '.$class.'" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
    /*if($page > $nb_pages)
    {
        $output .= '<a class="paginationLink" id="'.$i.'">Next</a>';
    }*/
    $output .=  "</div>";

    echo $output;
}

$output .= '
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="candidacyModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Candidature</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';

echo $output;
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#searchContent').keyup(function()
        {
            var search = $(this).val();
            var nb_per_page = $('.entriesData').val();
            var page = 1;

            loadContent(nb_per_page, search, page);
        });

        $('.entriesData').change(function ()
        {
            var nb_per_page = $(this).val();
            var search = $('#searchContent').val();
            var page = 1;

            loadContent(nb_per_page, search, page);

        });

        $('.paginationLink').on('click', function()
        {
            var page = $(this).attr('id');
            var nb_per_page = $('.entriesData').val();
            var search = $('#searchContent').val();
            //loadPagination(page);

            loadContent(nb_per_page, search, page);
        });

        $('.btnViewCandidacy').on('click', function () 
        {
            var candidacyId = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({  
                url:"viewCandidacy.php",  
                method:"get",  
                data:{candidacy:candidacyId},  
                success:function(data)
                {  
                    $('#modal-body').html(data);
                    $('#candidacyModal').modal("show");  
                }  
            });          
        });
    });
    
    function loadContent(nb_per_page, search, page)
    {
        var p = {};
        p['nb_per_page'] = nb_per_page;
        p['search'] = search;
        p['page'] = page;
        $.post("search.php", p, function(data)
        {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
                    <input type="text" name="searchContent" id="searchContent" placeholder="searchContent" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <label>Display<select name="entriesData" class="entriesData">
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
            résults</label>
            <div id="result">
            <?php include('search.php');?>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Could you add your loadContent code?

Comment: Added loadContent function @Communitylsridiculous

Answer (score 0):

please add jquery references like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jquery cdn added in snippet !